# Add Windows XP to the Windows 7 Boot Manager

Tags: windows-7, bootloader

I have two hard drives.  One hard drive is Windows 7 (A) and one is Windows XP (B).  I want to edit the boot-loader to show Windows 7 and Windows XP as choices.

The Boot-loader I'm using is Windows 7, as I installed Windows 7 after Windows XP.

Windows 7 is "Disc 0, Partition 0" 
Windows XP is "Disc 2, Partition 0"

How would I go about setting this up?  Is there a tool that can help me?

Thanks

EDIT: 
I've been reading about bcdedit, and the part that confuses me is I have no idea how it works.  The options people type in have no reference to drives or partitions, how does bcdedit "know" where stuff is?

Here are the options I have come up with so far:

bcdedit /create {ntldr} /d "Windows XP Professional" //add Windows to the list

//how do i tell bcdedit that XP is on Disk 2, Partition 0?

bcdedit /displayorder {ntldr} /addlast //make it so it's last

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 3):

The following article discusses the entire process from a to z in much detail and with many screen-shots. You're probably more interested in the later parts of the article.
[Windows 7 and Vista (and XP) Simple Multi-Boot Guide](http://www.tweaktown.com/articles/1713/windows_7_and_vista_and_xp_simple_multi_boot_guide/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

BCDedit is a tool included with Windows for the purpose of editing the boot menu.

Take a look at [this technet article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc709667%28WS.10%29.aspx) which discusses how to use it.

There is also a GUI program I used with Windows Vista, I didn't like it to much (over using BCDedit) but I will try to dig it up.

Comment: 6k, CG .. me just got hit with a 300pts 'karma loss' :)

Comment: ?

Comment: Sorry - What do you mean by that? what is 'karma loss'? :S I am confused :S

Comment: so am i      :)

Comment: Can you just explain CG and what you meant by your first comment?

Comment: oh, CG as in congratulations :)

Comment: oh... Thanks! It isn't a competition though... makes me feel good that I have helped but bad that I have spent so much time here!... still, what is Karma loss, and how did you loose 300?